# Ошибка при запуске PgAdmin

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Установил на Windows 10 Postgresql. При запуске вот такая ошибка.[image: ошибка]
Загуглил, нашёл инфу про исправление переменных окружения - не помогло. Если кто сталкивался - подскажите, пожалуйста, что делать. Второй день не могу запустить postgresql.

Comment: Так у вас PostgreSQL не запускается или pgAdmin всё-таки?

Comment: PostgreSQL - запускается, ну, по крайней мере ошибок нет, pgAdmin - не запускается.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin не запускается из-за кириллицы в имени профиля. Попробуй создать нового пользователя без кириллицы в имени.